# Embed Python code on a webpage

Tags: python, web

Is there an easy, simple way to embed python code in a webpage; i.e., have an embedded app where viewers input numbers and a python code is run and an output is spit out? I don't really want to learn Django just for one project, but if there's no other way, I might have to.

Comment: You need something like ipython notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flask. It only takes a few minutes to set up.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Recommend `flask`. I've just done something like this. Only need a few lines of python code and a few lines of html code. No more than 30 lines.

Write a html page which has an input and a button. When the page gets an input and the button gets hit, a python script will be invoked. And then result will be rendered to a new page.